# Show that $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} $ is a group under addition

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} $ is a group under addition.

I have little doubt about the closure property here what I tried

Let $[a],[b]\in \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$

Since $a \in [a]$ and $b \in [b]$ now $a+b=k \mod(8)$ so $[k] \in \{ [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]\}$.

That is,  $a+b \in [k]$. Therefore $[k]=[a+b]$  $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} $

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: Closure of addition is almost immediate, since any sum will have a remainder when divided by $8$. There is not much to prove here. What you should prove is that if $[a] = [a']$ and $[b] = [b']$, then $[a+b] = [a'+b']$. All other group properties are also almost immediate.

Comment: @Student Is my proof not correct?

Comment: The paragraph "Since  ..." does not make sense. Why "now", what is $k$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incomplete.

You need to show associativity, the existence of an identity, the existence of inverses, and that the operation is well-defined.

So far, you have only shown closure. What you have so far is fine.

Comment: Is proof of closure property correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I have edited my answer, @jvj.

Comment: Why do we need to prove operation is well defined? I haven't heard it I only show closure, associativity, existence of an identity, the existence of inverses,

Comment: You need it to show that the operation does not depend on the choice of coset representative, @jvj.